# complicated Mysql queries to generate a report

Tags: mysql

I have two tables products and stock_mvt

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (  
   `product_id`    int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
   `product_name`  varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
   `category_id`   int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
   `inventory`     int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
   `product_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',  
   `obs`           varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
   PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),  
   KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),  
   CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`category_id`) )
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=81 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `stock_mvt` 
(  `mvt_id`     int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   `trans_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
   `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
   `stock_plus` int(11) NOT NULL, 
   `stock_minus` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`mvt_id`),  
   KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),  
   CONSTRAINT `stock_mvt_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`product_id`) )
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=111 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And I want to generate a daily reports gathering :
Product_id, Product_name, Product_price, inventory before, Stock_plus, stock_minus, inventory after.
I have a lot queries to execute, lets just see the last ones :

```
SELECT 
      product_name, 
      inventory - ifnull( sum( stock_mvt.stock_minus ) , 0 ) 
                - ifnull( sum( stock_mvt.stock_plus ), 0 ) AS InventoryBF
   FROM
      products
         LEFT JOIN stock_mvt 
            ON products.product_id = stock_mvt.product_id
   WHERE 
      date( stock_mvt.trans_date ) < "2012-02-23"
   GROUP BY 
      products.product_name
```

To have the inventory before and

```
SELECT 
      product_name, 
      inventory - ifnull( sum( stock_mvt.stock_minus ) , 0 ) 
                - ifnull( sum( stock_mvt.stock_plus ) , 0 ) AS InventoryAf
   FROM
      products
         LEFT JOIN stock_mvt 
            ON products.product_id = stock_mvt.product_id
   WHERE
      date( stock_mvt.trans_date ) <= "2012-02-23"
   GROUP BY 
      products.product_name
```

to have the inventory after, those two Mysql query gave me just  products which had stock movements in that day and I want to have all products even with 0 movements the second problem  I can't do the union for All my queries, So my question is : please, is there a better way for me to do My query to have my report with all the data I want to show ? Thank you

Comment: in the second sql-statement I think '<=' should be '>='.

Comment: Thank you, but sql-statement are ok, and as I said my problem is how put it all to gether and obtain all the products listing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After formatting for readability of your original query, it makes sense now...  When you apply a WHERE clause, that causes an implied "INNER JOIN" unless you qualify it with NULL OR (whatever condition).  To keep it as a LEFT JOIN, move the date condition qualifier up to the LEFT JOIN portion...

```
LEFT JOIN STOCK_MVT
   ON  product...
   AND Date( trans_date ) ...
```

and remove the Date() qualifier from the WHERE clause

Comment: this works for me Thx, It makes sense for me yeah, now I'll try to put all together and I'll feed back